# Howto display unicode character \u2026 in terminal mode in emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs, unicode, term

*Magit* uses Horizontal Ellipsis unicode escape "\u2026" (which should display as "...") to mark hidden section. How can I configure the Terminal/Emacs to display them when running in terminal mode (option *-nw*)? The escape string is shown instead of the visual icon. Maybe I need to install a special font? I'm running emacs 26.1 running inside KDE Kconsole terminal emulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that I missed this in my .emacs.d configuration:

```
;; UTF-8 support
(prefer-coding-system       'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)    
(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
```

(from [here](http://www.skybert.net/emacs/how-to-get-unicode-in-the-terminal/)). The other possibility is to

```
(setq magit-section-visibility-indicator  '("..." . t))
```

instead (3 char string istead of one unicode char). KDE Konsole itself does support the \u2026 char as can be seen when printing the utf-8 sequence:

```
printf "\xe2\x80\xa6"
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved some broader terminal issues for me where output appeared all garbled. I hadn't until now figured out where the problem was exactly, but this solved it.

Answer (score 3):

When running in -nw mode, Emacs' display is at the mercy of the terminal emulator. If the emulator is using a font which doesn't have a glyph for the character you want to display, the only solution is to change it to use a different font.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't answer the question. The terminal emulator decides between showing `…` and something like `�` and Emacs has no way to know which one it is AFAIK. Emacs decides whether to attempt to display `…` or to display `\uNNNN`.

Comment: I fail to see how it doesn't answer the question: the font being used is missing a glyph. Switching to a different font will fix that. (and it's magit deciding to use the unicode sequence, not Emacs)

Comment: No, if Emacs displays `\uNNNN` in a terminal, that's because Emacs has decided to display `\uNNNN`. This has nothing to do with the font used in the terminal. If Emacs decided to display the character `…` and the font didn't have this character, you'd see something like `�` instead, the terminal would not substitute `\uNNNN`.